# How to clear JMapFrame with multiple layers

Tags: java, geotools

Is there any way to clear a JMapFrame and all of its layers before opening a new file? I currently am running into an error (exception no stack trace) while opening a file with one already open that has multiple layers added to it (with the layers pane).

```
    fileMenu.add(new SafeAction("Open File...") {
            @Override
            public void action(ActionEvent e) throws Throwable {


                setJFCFilter("Shapefiles", "shp");
                int returnVal = jfc.showOpenDialog(jframe);

                if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    String pathname = jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
                    URL shape = acquireURL(pathname);

                    if (shape == null) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jframe, "could not find file \"" + pathname + "\"", "Could not find file",
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }

                    try {
                        if (layers_size > 1) {
                            for (int i = 0; i < layerList.size(); i++) {
                                map.removeLayer(layerList.get(i));
                            }

                            jframe.revalidate();
                            jframe.repaint();

                            shapeFile = new File(pathname);
                            loadFile(shape);

                            worldAf = jframe.getMapPane().getScreenToWorldTransform();
                            scaleRatio = new BigDecimal(worldAf.getScaleX()); // NullPointer - Exception 2
                        } else {
                            shapeFile = new File(pathname);
                            loadFile(shape);

                            worldAf = jframe.getMapPane().getScreenToWorldTransform();
                            scaleRatio = new BigDecimal(worldAf.getScaleX());
                        }

                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(ShapefileExporter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            } // End Action
        }); // End Listener
```

**Load File**

```
// Load shapefile into JMapFrame
            protected void loadFile(URL shape) throws IOException {
                try {

                    FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(shape);
                    featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

                    ShapefileDataStore ds = new ShapefileDataStore(shape);
                    FeatureSource<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> fs = ds.getFeatureSource();

                    collection = fs.getFeatures();
                    FeatureArray = features();

                    map = new MapContent();
                    Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());

                    Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
                    map.addLayer(layer);

                    layerList = new ArrayList();
                    layerList.add(layer);

                    jframe.setMapContent(map); // NullPointer - Exception 1
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ShapefileExporter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
```

After running this bit of code, I run some more to add a layer. Once this second layer has been added if I run this code again (opening a different file) the exception happens.

Also I don't think I can post the full code as its over 1000 lines of code.

**Exception 1**

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.swing.MapLayerTableCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(MapLayerTableCellRenderer.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.updateLayoutState(BasicListUI.java:1361)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState(BasicListUI.java:1311)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.getPreferredSize(BasicListUI.java:578)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getPreferredSize(JComponent.java:1661)
    at javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout.layoutContainer(ScrollPaneLayout.java:790)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1503)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1492)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1688)
    at java.awt.Container.validate(Container.java:1623)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:691)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$2.run(RepaintManager.java:689)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.validateInvalidComponents(RepaintManager.java:688)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1676)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

**Exception 2**

```
Dec 31, 2015 3:01:09 PM com.mycompany.shapefileexporter.mvn.ShapefileExporter$1 action
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.shapefileexporter.mvn.ShapefileExporter$1.action(ShapefileExporter.java:249)
    at org.geotools.swing.action.SafeAction.actionPerformed(SafeAction.java:50)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at com.apple.laf.AquaMenuItemUI.doClick(AquaMenuItemUI.java:157)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

**Update:** Followed @iant advice and still running into null pointer exceptions, and the layers, after removing are still there (I managed to delete one but received multiple null pointer exceptions).

**Update: 12/30/15**
In open file menu item (above), attempting to reset the JMapFrame, nothing shows the frame just blinks and stays the same.

```
jframe.setVisible(false);
jframe.repaint();
initialize();
jframe.repaint();

shapeFile = new File(pathname);
loadFile(shape);
```

Comment: You go through the layers list and remove each layer in turn.

Comment: At least tell us what the exception is, maybe run in a debugger to find the issue.

Comment: how do i get the layer list?

Comment: I just used `List<Layer> layers = jframe.getMapContent().layers();
                        System.out.println("Layers: " + layers.size());` Which either gives me 1 layer or a null pointer

Comment: Using this: (does not work) `for (int i = 0; i < map.layers().size(); i++) {
                                map.layers().get(i).dispose();
                            }`

Comment: Still haven't solved this, kinda at a loss at the moment and this is the last thing I need done. Nothing I do works, either I get an exception or nothing happens. I just need to either remove the layers (currently 2) or clear the map to be able to open a new file (which is what is not working).

Comment: What does the debugger show?

Comment: If I try to remove layers or clear (dispose) of the map or map content in any way I get what is posted above, null pointers where I am clearing or removing. I also tried to reset the JMapFrame (clear that instead), but all it does it blink and stays the same. I tried re-initializing and also hiding the current frame and creating a new one. All my attempts (at restarting the application/frame) get me the same results, nothing and no debugger. The only exception I keep getting is null pointer while clearing map or deleting layers.

Comment: what happens when you run the program in your debugger and step up to the line with the null pointer exception? Or you need to provide a minimum example that I can run in a debugger to find out for you. You can also try turning up the logging level (see http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/conventions/code/log.html)

Comment: Added update with nullpointer exception, happens at line `jframe.setMapContent(map)`. Also I don't know what you mean by "turning up the logging level" as the link does not mention that at all, only reducing it using `.finer`

Comment: I think I sort of figured out the issue, although I am still unsure as to _why_ its and issue and how to solve it. I managed to edit my code to where it doesn't add another layer and instead edits or overwrites the default layer with the information I need. However I still get the same issue. Also I am unable to even close the jframe after the layer is edited. It's either something do to with the style or some variable that I am unable to dispose of.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (it works great in my program)

```
map.layers().clear();
```

Comment: Pretty sure I've tried that and it doesn't work, normally it would. But there is some error in the library that is causing an exception, nothing can be done to fix it unless the error is fixed.

Comment: have you tried this

/*     if (mapPane != null && mapPane.getMapContent() != null) {
        for (Layer layer : mapPane.getMapContent().layers()) {
         mapPane.getMapContent().removeLayer(layer);
        }
    }*/